# How to make dynamic state with select in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, redux, state

I have array of categoriesData(dynamic select per items), and array of interests, I need to show  depending on the amount categoriesData with the state dynamics.

this is my state:

```
{
  "categoriesData": [
    "Sports",
    "Pets"
  ],
  "interests": [
    "Travel & Tourism",
    "Technology & Science",
    "Sports",
    "Restaurants",
    "Photography",
    "Pets",
    "Music",
    "Movies and TV",
    "How-to &amp; Style",
  ]
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="row">
        <span>Categorias:</span>
            {this.state.categoriesData.map((item,index) => { 
                return (<select value= {item} onChange={(event) => this.categoriesData[????]}>
                    <option value= "" />
                    {this.state.interests.map((_item,i) =>
                        <option key={i}  value={_item}>{_item} 
                    </option>
                    )}
                </select>) 
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I show two input select with selected value correctly and the options goods..

the problems is that the value of the select is not updated because I do not know what would be the state to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save the interest as a list of dictionary, key value pair where value can be the selected|unselected.

```
`"interests": 
     [
        {"Travel & Tourism": false},
        {"Technology & Science" : true}, 
        {"Restaurants": false}
     ]`
```